# Scroll To And Highlight Div When Link Is Clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to highlight a div that wraps a contact form so the user knows where to go to contact. my link will be something like this

```
<a href="#form" class="contacthighlight">Contact Us</a>
```

Going with a class since this will be used on the site in two places.

right now the current background for #form is #f5f5f5 so what I want to do is Flash a random color like #ff0000 and slowly fade it out back to #f5f5f5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2928193)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Target pseudo­-class applied to element which you are scrolled to.
Add this to your css:

**CSS:**

```
#form {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#form {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#form:target {
    animation: target-fade 1s 1;
}

@keyframes target-fade {
    0% { background-color: #ff0000; }
    100% { background-color: #f5f5f5; }
}
```

**HTML markup:**

```
<a href="#form"> link to target #form</a>
<form id="form">
    …
</form>
```

**PS:**
Accordingly to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) CSS properties: [animation and keyframes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) is needed vendor **prefixes** such this:

```
.box_animation:hover {
  -webkit-animation: myanim 1s infinite; /* value is demo only */
     -moz-animation: myanim 1s infinite;
       -o-animation: myanim 1s infinite;
          animation: myanim 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim {…}
@-moz-keyframes myanim {…}
@-o-keyframes myanim {…}
@keyframes myanim {…}
```

**PPS:** *dabblet* using [prefix free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) JS library to paste all necessary prefixes. Later without this *library* you can see all you need **prefix syntax** on [**css3please**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Comment: This works in the dabblet but for some reason when I copy and paste the code into my css file it doesnt work even though everything is the same

Comment: It is because my example not using *vendor* prefixes (for clear understand), because of dabblet using [prefix free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) JS library to paste all neccessary prefixes. Without this *library* you can see all you need **prefix syntax** on [**css3please**](http://css3please.com/)

Comment: @JoeBobby I added explanation to answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ariel Flesler's [ScrollTo jQuery Plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to scroll with animation.

And for changing color with animation you use the [jQuery Color Animation Plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

example

```
$('selector').scrollTo( '520px', 800 )
.animate({backgroundColor:'#ff0000'}, {duration:5000,queue:false});
```

### Edits

If you want to fade it back you can use toggle function.

```
   $('selector').scrollTo( '520px', 800 )
   .toggle(function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
     {backgroundColor:'#ff0000'}, {duration:5000,queue:false});
   },
   function() {
   $(this).animate({
     {backgroundColor:'#f5f5f5'}, {duration:5000,queue:false});
   });
```

Comment: this works to fade the color in but how do I get it to fade back out so it can so when it's clicked again it highlights again?